# High order SML questions

Tags: sml, higher-order-functions

So, I am trying to create a high order SML function that takes in a number and returns all the functions and returns its factors. I have done questions where I would take a list of values and return the values that are divisible but I never did anything like take a number and make a list out of it. Following the question:

> Define a function `factorize = fn: int -> int list` that takes an integer and returns all its factors in a list. For example, `factorize 12` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]`.

The second one is a tricky one, I couldn't understand how its done so dropping it here. I would appreciate any help I get on this one.

> Define a function `cfoldl` that behaves exactly same as the standard `foldl` except that the type of the function argument does not take a 2-tuple’ instead, the input function should use the currying notation as is `’a -> ’b -> ’b`. Thus, the type of `cfoldl` should be `fn : (’a -> b -> ’b) -> ’b -> ’a list -> ’b`. For example, `cfoldl (fn a => fn b => a-b) 1 [1,2,3,4];` will return `3`.

I made this for the `foldl`:

```
fun cfoldl f b [] = b
  | cfoldl f b (x::xs) = cfoldl f (f (x, b)) xs;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You may find it useful to write a function `curry`.  With `fun curry f a b = f (a, b)`, you could write `curry op+` for instance, and get a curried version of the addition operator.

Answer (score 2):

> `factorize = fn: int -> int list` that takes an integer and returns all its factors in a list

Here's a recursive function that takes a number and generates a list of numbers from 1 up to that number:

```ml
fun upto n =
    let fun go i = if i < n
                   then i :: go (i+1)
                   else []
    in go 1
    end
```

Could you make a function `isFactor x y` that is true when `x` is a factor of `y`?

If you had such a function, could you modify the above function to make use of it?

> a function `cfoldl` that should use the currying notation as is `’a -> ’b -> ’b`
>
> ```ml
> fun cfoldl f b [] = b | cfoldl f b (x::xs) = cfoldl f (f (x, b)) xs;
> ```

This is exactly `foldl`.

```ml
fun foldl f e []      = e
  | foldl f e (x::xr) = foldl f (f(x, e)) xr;
```

Here, `f : ('a * 'b) -> 'b` because `f` is being used as `f(x, e)`, so naturally it will assume a tuple. You can change the inferred type of `f` by using it differently.

Can you think of a way where `f : 'a -> 'b -> 'b`?

Comment: Yes, I found a way to get f : 'a -> 'b -> 'b. fun cfoldl f b [] = b
| cfoldl f b (x::T) = cfoldl f (f x b) T;

Comment: For the 5th problem, I couldnt solve to go from 1 to i, so i cam from i to 1.
 fun factorize n =
 let 
  fun num 0 = []
  fun num x = if( x mod n = 0) then n :: num(x-1) else num(n-1)
 in
   num n
  end;  
This was my code for number 5. 
Thank you for hint, that helped out.